# How can I data transfer to another activity with databinding?

Tags: android

I am using MVVM architecture. I pull my data into Recyclerview with Retrofit. I also use databinding when doing operations.

When I click on an item in Recyclerview, I open a different activity. I want the text value in Recyclerview to appear on the other activity. And I want to do this with dataBinding. How can I do that?

[I want to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc2ar.png)

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, Pass the data by intent in on item click

```
override fun editItem(mTest: Test, index: Int) {
        if (mTest!= null) {

        }
    }
```

For more info check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60739905/7498057